# How can i specify the size of a text field in API sending

Tags: docusignapi

We are sending a document through API at a certain point the customer should be able to write a big block of text. Yet when putting a text field in the custom field without limitation you can only write until you get to the end of the page. and it does not continue on the line below.

[unlimited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx8DQ.png)

if you put fixed size i do not seem to be able to actually specify the width and hight of the field that a customer can use in de custom field set-up. and i only get a small field where you can place 1 character.

[fixed size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVy2O.png)

Does anyone now how to get around this?

We place the fields on the documents with predefined tags on the document and custom document fields

I tried to go to the other settings to see whether something could help me like the fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

DocuSign doesn't allow you to create a text box with unlimited size or for users to input text that extends off the page. I would recommend using the `height` and `width` properties to set the size of the tab to the max area where your user can input text. If you set the height property your tab will be able to include multiple lines of text. The json would look something like the snippet below. You can also enable [API request logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) which allows you to try setting tabs in the web app and then you can download the logs to see what the json looks like for the tabs you created.

```
"textTabs": [
  {
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "xPosition": "300",
    "yPosition": "400",
    "documentId": "1",
    "width": "100",
    "height": "30"
  }
]
```

Comment: We are working with predefined tags and the API just puts the custom fields on these tags. I suppose their is no way that we can set this width and heigt in the custom field settings? so that it can keep working with these tags. we have rather complicated contract sets with different amount of pages and different texts to fill in depending on which products clients take and the amount of clients involved in a contract. this is why we decided to work with the tags.